# Jquery - Hidel LI based on custom attribute mantaining other filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help to accomplish this since Im not good at all at jQuery / JavaScript, this is why I don't even know how to search for the answer:

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="searchParameter">
<ul>
    <li data-sr-geolocation="USA, Miami" style="display:none;"></li>
    <li data-sr-geolocation="Brazil, Sao Pablo"></li>
    <li data-sr-geolocation="Canada, Quebec"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide the li's based on the custom attribute value.

For example If on the **searchParameter** I put "Canada, Quebec" or "Quebec" (**Contains**) hide all the others li.

Since I have other filters applied (some li's are already hidden), I will just need to show just the ones that contains the value but are not already hidden by other filter even though they have the value searched.

Comment: _"I will just need to show just the ones that contains the value but are not already hidden."_ It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BlackSheep you are right... If they are already hidde. I will change it :)

Comment: Can you describe (or add the code for) how the other filters are working? That might help other people give you a compatible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly you can select the visible `li` elements, hide them and show the matching ones, this way your filtering doesn't involve already hidden elements:

```
$('li').not(':hidden')
       .hide()
       .filter('[data-sr-geolocation*="'+ searchParameter +'"]')
       .show();
```

Comment: I tried it, however now I have all the li hidden (if I put some other country not listed) but If I search again, nothing is found since everything has been hidden :(
I think my logic is bad... I will need to take a look at it :)

Comment: @MRFerocius Well, yes `not(':hidden')` on the second execution returns  an empty set, it would be helpful if you could post all the relevant code.

Comment: Guys, I am a monster! My logic is pretty bad, however your answer pointed me in the right path. Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS attribute selectors.

```
$('li').hide();
$('li[data-sr-geolocation*="'+searchString+'"]').show();
```

Comment: Since you are hiding all the elements your `.not(':hidden')` returns an empty collection.

Comment: @BlackSheep You're right.  Sorry, I got interrupted while answering this and lost my train of logic.  I've fixed it now.